# Reflexive relations for n = 0 on a set X - 1 or 0

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

I would like to ask you, why is the reflexive relation $0$ on the set X,  for $n = 0$, where $n$  - is the number of relations, and X is any 0-element set, i.e. empty.?

From the formula:

$2^{n^2-n}=2^{0^2-0}=2^{0}=1$

So where did the difference come from? I don't understand why we get the value $1$ from the formula for the number of reflexive relations, when it's definition says that it cannot be a reflexive relation.

I would be grateful for help.

Best wishes.

Comment: What's the question?  You appear to have omitted a great deal of context.  Like what the set $X$ is.  Or what "the reflexive relation $0$" might mean. Or what $n$ is.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Don't assume your readers can read your mind, and don't leave critical information for the comments.

Comment: Thank You for Your attention. I changed the content of the post.

Comment: There is only one relation on an empty set, namely the empty relation.  It is vacuously reflexive, as there is no element $a\in \emptyset$ which is not related to itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All clear. :)